# How to add a table as a header?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am working with **iTextSharp** trying to add an header and a footer to my generated PDF but, if I try to add an header that have width of 100% of my page I have some problem.

So I have do the following things:

1) I have create a class named **PdfHeaderFooter** that extends the iTextSharp **PdfPageEventHelper** class

2) Into **PdfHeaderFooter** I have implemented the **OnStartPage()** method that generate the header:

```
    // write on start of each page
    public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnStartPage(writer, document);
        PdfPTable tabHead = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 1F });
        PdfPCell cell;
        //tabHead.TotalWidth = 300F;
        tabHead.WidthPercentage = 100;

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header"));
        tabHead.AddCell(cell);
        tabHead.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 150, document.Top, writer.DirectContent);
    }
```

If I use sometning like **tabHead.TotalWidth = 300F;** insted **tabHead.WidthPercentage = 100;** it work well but if I try to set as 100% the width of the tabHead table (as I do in the previous example) when it call the **tabHead.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 150, document.Top, writer.DirectContent)** method it throw the following exception:

> **The table width must be greater than zero.**

Why? What is the problem? How is it possible that the table have 0 size if I am setting it to 100%?

Someone can help me to solve this issue?

Tnx

Comment: Think about what a percentage *is*.  You are setting the width percentage to 100% of nothing.  I believe you still have to set the `TotalWidth`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `writeSelectedRows()`, it doesn't make sense to set the width percentage to 100%. Setting the width percentage is meant for when you add a document using `document.add()` (which is a method you can't use in a page event). When using `document.add()`, iText calculates the width of the table based on the page size and the margins.

You are using `writeSelectedRows()`, which means you are responsible to define the size and the coordinates of the table.

If you want the table to span the complete width of the page, you need:

```
table.TotalWidth = document.Right - document.Left;
```

You're also using the wrong X-coordinate: you should use `document.Left` instead of `150`.

**Additional info:**

- The first two parameters define the start row and the end row. In your case, you start with row 0 which is the first row, and you don't define an end row (that's what -1 means) in which case all rows are drawn.
- You omitted the parameters for the columns (there's a variation of the `writeSelectedRows()` that expects 7 parameters).
- Next you have the X and Y value of start coordinate for the table.
- Finally, you pass a `PdfContentByte` instance. This is the canvas on which you're drawing the table.

Comment: can you explain me wath exactly mean the meaning of the 5 WriteSelectedRows() paramethers?